# How do I call a custom method on a model with a template in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, twitter-bootstrap, methods

I'm trying to make a poll app, and I'm kinda stuck on the "view poll" page.

I want to display the votes with a Twitter Bootstrap progress bar, and I wrote a method in the Choice model to calculate the percentage compared to all the other choices on the poll.

However, when I try doing `{{ choice.percentage }}` it just returns... blank. nothing.

Screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Here's `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

    def percentage(self):
        total = 0.0
        for ch in self.poll.choice_set.all():
            total = total + ch
        return (self.votes/total)*100
```

And here's `view_poll.html`:

```
{% extends "quickpoll_web/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Viewing poll #{{ poll.id }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title text-center">{{ poll.question }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        {% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-right">{{ choice.choice_text }}</div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{ choice.percentage }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{ choice.percentage_of_votes }}%">
                        <span class="sr-only">{{ choice.votes }} out of {{ total_votes }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is `percentage_of_votes` defined? You set the style to `width:  {{ choice.percentage_of_votes }}%`.

Comment: What do you get if you `def percentage(self): return 50`? This would determine if percentage is getting called like you expect and would point to a broken query.

Comment: And what does your browser tell you is the *source* of the page? can you see the `<div class="progress">` tag in your browser developer tools?

Comment: @msw If I replace it with return 50, it's still blank.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's just a leftover from renaming it to fit SO, if I fix that, it's still blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this method:

```
def percentage(self):
    total = 0.0
    for ch in self.poll.choice_set.all():
        total = total + ch
    return (self.votes/total)*100
```

`self.poll.choice_set.all():` returns a queryset of `Choice` objects.

Now, in the view if you try to do `choice.percentage()`, you will notice the error.

To fix this, try

```
def percentage(self):
    total = 0.0
    for ch in self.poll.choice_set.all():
        total = total + ch.votes
    return (self.votes/total)*100
```