# How Do I Get Django Poll Votes In Percentage Format?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I used the tutorial to create a polling app...and I've been expanding on it...I've got it working...but I can't figure out how to turn the votes into percentages...

I have tried to do something like...

```
def percentage(self):
     return 100 * (self.votes) / (self.survey)
```

But this isn't working...

My models look like...

```
class Choice(models.Model):
 
    choice = models.TextField(max_length=264,blank=True,null=True,unique=False)
    survey = models.ForeignKey("Survey",on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="choice_survey")
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Survey(models.Model):
 
    survey_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True,unique=False)
    survey_type = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES8,blank=True,max_length=300)
```

I've seen examples of annotate and I've played with them as well.  Do I need to keep track of the total number of votes as an attribute?  The other examples I've seen are all foreignkey.  I can totally get the number of votes by getting the integerfield.  I just can't seem to figure out how to convert this into a percentage.

Comment: I was able to do what I wanted based on this prior SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933943/how-do-i-call-a-custom-method-on-a-model-with-a-template-in-django/18934029#18934029

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my question leveraging the solution documented here....

[How do I call a custom method on a model with a template in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933943/how-do-i-call-a-custom-method-on-a-model-with-a-template-in-django/18934029#18934029)

My final answer looks like....

```
def percentage(self):
    total = 0.0
    for choice in self.poll.choice_set.all():
        total = total + choice.votes
    return (self.votes/total)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

A percentage is a fraction of a particular value. In this case, you need  something to compare the number of votes for this choice against - eg, the number of all votes for all choices.

Assuming you have a very simply survey (eg, only one multiple-choice question) then you can obtain this number by

```
def percentage(self):
     total_votes = Choice.objects.filter(survey=self.survey).count()
     return (self.votes / total_votes) * 100
```

If you have many questions in your survey, then you'll need an intermediate model, like Question, so that a survey holds many questions, and they, in turn, have many choices.  Then you can do the same thing with Question that we have with survey above.